# PHP and Mysql select query issue

Tags: php, mysql

Well im working on a small php script and i made a query to connect to db like this:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['keyword']));
$query = mysql_query("select * from kalimat WHERE name LIKE '%$id%' OR content like '%$id%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<a href='interpretation-".$row['id'].".html'><li>".$row['name']."</li></a>";
}
```

Now i want to echo the result of select from names then echo the result of selecting from content thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not use the mysql_ functions, theyre deprecated. Use mysqli instead

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do? Do you want to make new select statements or just check which of the results matched on name and which on content? Maybe use an if statement to check if name or content matches?

Comment: please explain it more...

Comment: @aniri the current querry show me result in random order i want to show the records that match the name then the records than match the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
   select * from kalimat WHERE name LIKE '%$id%' OR content like '%$id%'
   order by  CASE WHEN name    LIKE '%$id%' THEN 0
                  WHEN content LIKE '%$id%' THEN 1 END
```